# ASP.NET c# Creating a PDF (both Rotativa and ITextSharp) how to modify the ViewerPreferences dictionary to turn off print scaling in adobe readier

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, rdlc, rotativa

We are generating PDFS from a web app a couple different ways, ItextASharp, Html->Rotativa, and RDLC...

Is there any way in anyof those tools to modify the ViewerPreferences dictionary inside the PDF so as to disable the "shrink to fit" option..

The PDF format supports this option, I've found documentation for that...

I'm aware that not all viewers honor the request not to shrink to fit, but we're using stock adobe readers across the board so it's ok.

I was able to find this in ITextSharp to read one, modify it and save, it, so I have to believe there is a way to set it before generation...but I can't find it..

[Determine properties such as if PDF is Simplex or Duplex in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200641/determine-properties-such-as-if-pdf-is-simplex-or-duplex-in-itextsharp)

It'd be awesome if Rotativa had a way too...since we use that for some reports

We also have some done in RDLC style, if there is a way to do it there...

The reason we have to do it, is one of our apps prints labels and the amount of data leave no room for fudging it. Printing them from a web app is problematic, even when we control the ecosystem.

Unfortunately, our IT group will not use the reg settings to change the default on the machines.. we have to do it through code.

Comment: I found a way in IText sharp.. still looking for the other two...


http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/avoid-oversized-pages-td2137060.html

Adding a line to set the viewer preferences like this: 
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, os); 
writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.printScalingNone); 
will tell Adobe Reader the document shouldn't be 'fit to paper'.

Comment: Nope turns out that the ITextSharp way is deprecated, the methods don't exist in the version it ItextSharp we are using...back at zero