# JavaScript for Acrobat: duplex printing without using booklets

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I want to enable duplex-mode of a printer automatically by just opening a PDF file in a browser. this code works completely fine - also setting it to duplex-mode works. the only big problem is: it is setting the page-handling to booklet-style.

```
var pp = this.getPrintParams();

pp.printerName = "Company Printer Name";

pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;

pp.pageHandling = pp.constants.handling.booklet;

pp.booklet.binding = pp.constants.bookletBindings.Left;

pp.booklet.duplexMode = pp.constants.bookletDuplexModes.BothSides;

this.print(pp);
```

you find this example a couple of times, also in the official Adobe documentation: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

but it's always just referring to the booklet-page style.

is there  a possibility to change to duplex-mode without being in booklet mode? (preferably with pdf js)

**update:**
I managed to set my duplexmode successfully by changing the PDF's source adding these lines (using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)):

```
/ViewerPreferences<<
/Duplex /DuplexFlipLongEdge
>>
```

the duplex-mode is set in the print dialog, but it is ignored when you silently print it with adobe js. it works when you manually click the "print" button in the print dialog though.

so my "bonus"-question is: how do i automatically (silently) print it with adobe js without ignoring the document's settings? maybe some delay could help here?

Comment: As far as I understand it, Duplex printing is provided by the printer driver, and not by Acrobat (except via the booklet object in the printparams).

Comment: @MaxWyss that's what i have thought as well until i saw this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23201241/3391783

Comment: Yeah, I see. Problem is that we do not have access to those parameters with JavaScript.

Comment: @MaxWyss yes. but i managed to change the pdf's source. but automatically printing with js ignores the duplex settings while they are visible in the printing dialog. see my updated answer.